# How to remove table name in the column names in the query?

Tags: sql, hive

I have a hive query that looks like this:

```
set hive.cli.print.header=true;
select x1, x2, x3 from table1
union all
select x1, x2, x3 from table2
```

The problem is that, the hive automatically adds a new table name to the column names, so the column names in the result looks like this:

```
_u1.x1  _u1.x2  _u1.x3
```

I don't want the "_u1." How can I simply keep the column names as:

```
x1  x2  x3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select x1, x2, x3 from
(select x1, x2, x3 from table1
union all
select x1, x2, x3 from table2) as test;
```

***Before:***

```
select order_id,order_date from orders limit 1
union all
select order_id,order_date from orders limit 1;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_u1.order_id    _u1.order_date
1   2013-07-25 00:00:00.0
1   2013-07-25 00:00:00.0
```

***After:***

```
select order_id, order_date from
(select order_id,order_date from orders limit 1
union all
select order_id,order_date from orders limit 1) as test;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
order_id    order_date
1   2013-07-25 00:00:00.0
1   2013-07-25 00:00:00.0
```

Comment: thanks, but is it possible to redefine the column name directly? Without add a new line of select ....

Comment: No, there is not any option like that to best of my knowledge.